# video calling / video conferencing using Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova

In one of my application using Phonegap has video conferencing functionality for iPhone and Android. I just want to know  is it possible using Phonegap or we need to connect some Objective C code within our Phonegap project for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PhoneGap plug-in for this purpose (which in reality is the native Obj C etc code). Fortunately for you, there is already such a plug-in available, but it is iOS only:

https://github.com/opentok/PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Thanks for reply dear. Yes i know but i want for android also then need to be code in native only.